# All US cities in GEOJSON

Tags: data-request, usa

Is there a data set that contains all US cities in GEOJSON format? I saw something about Mapzen having it, but looks like they don't provide it anymore.

Did anyone download this or know where I can find something similar?

Comment: Could you find the data in another format and convert? What data are you looking for? The sort geonames provides? The sort wikidata provides? Or more?

Comment: also polygon or point? what?

Comment: I need the format like the output from http://geojson.io   Trying to create boundaries for each city, so will need the polygon format.

Answer (score 2):

check this :

> [data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov) , The home of the U.S. Government’s open data
>
> https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=GeoJSON

Comment: Yea, I've seen this but it is usually specific to one city. I'm looking for all cities int he US. Or, is that a crazy task?

Comment: i think there must be a way to combine data sets for these individual cities into one single set , is that what you seek ?

Comment: Yea, or if there is a GEOJSON file for each state, and that state file has all of their cities in it. I just need all of the cities in the US, if it is 1 file or 50 it doesn't really matter to me. Just need the GEOJSON for all cities. Does that make sense? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This github repo has all US city boundaries in GeoJSON format:

https://github.com/generalpiston/geojson-us-city-boundaries

It's derived from the US Census TIGER data.